# Log4J JDBC SQL Error in Referenced Jar

Tags: java, oracle, hadoop, log4j

I'm writing a Java application that uses Hadoop which uses Log4j as far as I understand. In my application, Log4J works fine. I'm using a JDBCAppender to write to an Oracle database. What's happening is that as I'm running the application, in the Hadoop jar during a log4j call it crashes and gives a missing comma error. It's strange since it works in my part of the program but crashes in the Hadoop stuff. I turned on debugging in log4j and everything looks normal.

My questions are the following.
1) Is it possible somehow to turn on additional logging within JDBCAppender to see what the SQL statement is that's offending?
2) How the heck should I approach this! :)

Here is the exception and log4j.properties file.

```
log4j:ERROR Failed to excute sql
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00917: missing comma

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:505)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:223)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1033)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1328)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1837)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1802)
at         oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:294)
at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.execute(JDBCAppender.java:218)
at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.flushBuffer(JDBCAppender.java:289)
at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.append(JDBCAppender.java:186)
at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
at     org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.info(Log4JLogger.java:199)
at     org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:173)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task.commit(Task.java:1012)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task.done(Task.java:882)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:374)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
I/O error: Read timed out
```

And the properties file...

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, DB

log4j.appender.DB = org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender

log4j.appender.DB.URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.0.18:1521/dev01.home.net
log4j.appender.DB.driver = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
log4j.appender.DB.user = syslog
log4j.appender.DB.password = syslog
log4j.appender.DB.sql = INSERT INTO SERVICELOG values (log4net_seq.nextVal, sysdate, '%p', null, '%m','')
log4j.appender.DB.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

EDIT 0

Actually, I think I may be on to something. There's a single quote in the string that it's trying to print. That's a no-no character for Oracle. Now I just need to figure out how to remove it :).

/EDIT 0

Comment: Where does the I/O error seem to occur? Is it the database connectivity?

Comment: I think that the I/O error at the bottom is unrelated. Sorry about that. I got it even when everything was running fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. Hadoop had single quotes in their logs which was screwing up writes to Oracle. I implemented a hack and modified log4j to strip out single quotes. The changes were in Category.java in the forcedLog function. I check to see if the incoming object is an instanceof String. Then I take that string and do a replaceAll("'","") on it. I could've done a replaceAll("'","''") to make the single quote palatable for Oracle but it doesn't matter for me.

Comment: you can also give this project a try http://www.dankomannhaupt.de/projects/index.html

Comment: or you can try something like this (using oracle quotes) - appender.setSql("INSERT INTO LOGS (ID,DATED,LOGGER,LOGLEVEL,MESSAGE) VALUES (logs_seq.nextval,sysdate,'%C','%p',q'[%m]')");

Answer (score 0):

1 : 
You can define the log level of your happender very easily :
    log4j.appender.DB = DEBUG
You can even set the log level for a specific package like this`com.foobar = DEBUG`.

2 You have probably a version conflict on log4j. The simplest way may be to use exactly the same version than the one used by Hadoop. Other one may be to switch to another logger implementation for your app like logback.

The last one is to exclude log4j transitive dependencies of hadoop if both project use maven but there is no guarantee on the result.